# Process to Apply Non Slip Coating to Wood Flooring

Tags: hardwood-floor

I hardwood floors in my house and we have a new puppy. No matter how short her claws and paw hair is she slips like Scooby Do. We need a non slip coating to prevent this.

I found a product that looks perfect: Bona Traffic HD Anti Slip Satin. However, I’m stuck on the prep required for an already finished floor. I know prep is 85% of the job so that it is super important.

The directions say to sand with 80 grit following all the way to 220 grit. I’m not able to clear out my house in order to kick this much dust up.

Is there another way to prep for this product, or maybe there’s a product better for me?

Comment: You could trust the puppy to learn to deal with the floors...

Comment: Puppies grow up fast.  It seems like a lot of work for a month or two.

Comment: There are dog shoes with rubber soles, if you're dead-set on a product solution.

Comment: Anything you apply to the floors is likely to damage their look more than an occasional scrabbling of claws

Comment: Get some area rugs with nonskid backing.  Place them in strategic spots on the slippery floor.  Pupper will learn to accelerate off the rugs and coast across the floor.  Then when she grows up, she'll get heavier and it'll be easier to walk on the floor.